# Why metaclass works for a class propery but a @classmethod @property doesn't?

Tags: python, properties, metaclass

It's a simplified reimplementation of Django deb models.

This works (similar to what Django does, although there it's an attribute, not a property):

```py
class ClassPropertyType(type):
    @property
    def objects(cls):
        return cls.init_empty_storage_if_needed()


class Model(metaclass=ClassPropertyType):
    @classmethod
    def init_empty_storage_if_needed(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, "__objects_storage"):
            cls.__objects_storage = ObjectStorage(cls)
        return cls.__objects_storage


class ObjectStorage:
    def __init__(self, model_class):
        pass

    def all(self):
        pass

Model.objects.all()
```

This:

```py
class Model:
    @classmethod
    def init_empty_storage_if_needed(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, "__objects_storage"):
            cls.__objects_storage = ObjectStorage(cls)
        return cls.__objects_storage

    @classmethod
    @property
    def objects(cls):
        return cls.init_empty_storage_if_needed()


class ObjectStorage:
    def __init__(self, model_class):
        pass

    def all(self):
        pass

Model.objects.all()
```

gives an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classmethod_property.py", line 21, in <module>
    Model.objects.all()
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'all'
```

I'd like to use the more intuitive @classmethod+@property way. How to make it do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works -
It is just that `classmethod` was modified to play nicely with `property` in a recent Python (I think only in 3.10).

Before that, if you think, a `property` decorator transforms the method in a very different object than a method: without specific code,  there is no way "classmethod" would work with it in a transparent way.

Under the hood, what takes place is: for both classmethods and properties,
when retriveing the attribute from the class, like in `Model.objects`, the Python runtime checks if the object bound to `objects` on the `Model` class body has a `__get__` method. (both `property`, `classmethod` and function objects implement this). That is called with "instance=None, owner=Model" parameters.  A regular "property" when getting "instance=None" will return itself: it is the regular way for retrieving the property. In newer Python, a classmethod checks it is decorating a property, and not a regular function, and make the appropriate calls.

As for "metaclasses" - a method or property in a metaclass is just a regular method or property for the metaclass instance (the metaclass'classes) - the `property` is not wrapped or transformed like what takes place when you decorate it with `classmethod`. That is why it works in older Python: the normal language mechanisms are used - a `MetaModel.objects` property would be called with `instance=Model, owner=MetaModel` for a `Model.objects` access, and then translate that call to a call into the original `objects` function placing the instance (`Model`)  as the first parameter (`self`), just like regular "instance" properties work.